# Manual incrementation of a feild column (int) form a specific point and row. (Not ID)

Tags: mysql

So basically  I have an (ID) field that is auto incremented

There is another field that kinda serves as a counter (Counter_ID) for users, everytime a new user of our web site registers that feild in MySql fills up with a incremental number.

Example:

[image]

My question: How do I reset the Counter_ID to start from 1 again (1,2,3 etc)? For example I want it to reset in row where Susan is and to start incrementing from there again. The result would be the following:

[image]

I am not the original developer of this database and web site so I'm not sure how was the incrementation done in the first place, by the end of every year he always reset to start incrementation from the last user registered.

I'm currently using **phpMyAdmin**.

Comment: At the office so I can't see the images. Concretely: when/why do you want to reset the counter? What is the logic behind this reset and how do you want it implemented (automatically or manually) ?

Comment: Basically I want to manually increment a field that has an integer value and it's not ID. Every year it gets manually incremented , so for example on dec 31 the number is 250 and od January when new user registered it number will be  251 but it should be 1.

When I suer registers it's written in database and the php code takes those values form the table and dysplays it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to fully understand the question, but, it seems that you dont know in what part of the code this Counter_ID gets updated.

Anyway, considering your example, being: -i changed the values so as counter_id and id not to be the same, just for clarity-:

> Id, counter_id, name
>
> 100, 41, Susan
>
> 101, 42, Lee

You could update your table executing the query:

**UPDATE table SET counter_id = counter_id - 40 WHERE id >= 100**

then you will get

> 100, 1, Susan
>
> 101, 2, Lee

Comment: Ty for replying. It did not work tho, I got some weird decrements :D Please see my new comment with updated screenshots from the table, it's a little bit more clearer about what I'm trying to do. Please reply when you have the time. Ty.

Comment: Can you see if there is a TRIGGER defined in the table? That should be the way this field is incremented. It must take the value of the previus row and then incremented by one. If that is the case you coudl re write the trigger to change to one at the first day of the year. Or manualy update all the records added the new year, and then, for the new ones INSERTED after that, the trigger should take care of the increment. Cheers

Comment: There are no triggers but maybe I could create one? Would that work? :D

Comment: If you are sure there are no TRIGGERs involved, then I'd suggest you stick to manually update all the records of the new year (i.e. if when you arrive to work on january 1st there are 5 clients inserted, then change the 5 of them manually -the query above should work..-, then for the following ones, the database/script should take care of that index.

Comment: Thanks mate, I will try the script again, I probably didn't wrote it right :)

Comment: Hey man the script is perfect! Thank you! You solved my problem :)

Comment: Glad to help!! :) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the replies guys. I’ll explain it a little bit better. So there is this [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kz6ah.png). The ID is auto incremented and the counter is also incremented although I don’t exactly know how because  I’m new here and I am not the one that made this database.

After every year the “counter” gets manually incremented again while the ID stays the same [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWFuD.png).

I have been told that every year I have to change it to start form 1 again and it goes on incrementing by it's self until time comes to “reset” it again. This is what I’m trying to do.